# SSH Into Google Cloud Compute Engine

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, gcloud

Every time I try I receive this error

```
username@xx.xx.xx.xx: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Can anyone explain why? I have added the SSH key to the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Your question would benefit from more detail.

What did you try?

Assuming you picked the default (metadata) [mechanism](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance) when you created the VM, you used a Google-provided image, the instance has a public IP and sshd is running on port 22, the easiest way to SSH in to an instance is:

```sh
INSTANCE=[[YOUR-INSTANCE-NAME]]
PROJECT=[[YOUR-PROJECT-NAME]]
ZONE=[[ZONE]] # The zone where the instance was created

gcloud compute ssh ${INSTANCE} --project=${PROJECT} --zone=${ZONE}
```

Alternatively, if you chose OS Login see [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access)

Comment: Yeah I have been trying to ssh without gcloud?  is that possible or is the cli required?

Comment: To add to what I did, I added the SSH key to the metadata and into the firewall section, I then ran `ssh mac@ip.ip.ip.ip`

Comment: You can do it manually to e.g. use your own keys, see: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys

Comment: I’ve followed that and the same problem happens public key error

Comment: Are you able to ssh into the instance using `gcloud`? I know you'd prefer to SSH directly but this will eliminate the instance's config from your problems. If `gcloud compute ssh` works, then it's something you're doing. If `gcloud compute ssh` doesn't work, then it's a problem with the instance, IP, firewall etc.

Comment: Hmm what are the instance settings required for SSH?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions to [troubleshoot the permission denied error](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/67997017#comment4) and also provided some background information what's going on for SSH to work with gcloud compute ssh.